# Please can you help me identify this

Tags: winter-gardening

[image]

I have found this growing through out a newly purchased allotment, the root is really thick and almost looks like asparagus stems but has these small leaves started to break through the surface! Please help!

Comment: Hello Sam,   Welcome.  Please tell us where you are located?  This will help narrow down the weeds that grow in your area.  Is this weed popping up in the yard, in a flower bed?   Do you have pictures of it in the ground?  Any information you can provide will help.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I am located down the south of england in hampshire. It is coming up in an allotment patch in the back garden which wasnt used for purpose for a couple of years as the previous owner was very old. I don't currently have a photo of it in the ground but I can take one next time I am at the house. Any help you can provide would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure @Bamboo will be able to answer your  question, also from the UK.

Comment: I can't really tell all that well the leaves but I'm wondering if it is a type of dock or burdock. Are the roots horizontal or vertical?

Comment: I;m not recognisiing this at the moment, but I know allotmenteers - I bet another grower on the alllotments knows exactly what it is, especially if its a problem plant, so ask. Otherwise, need to see a bit more growth and what it looks llike insitu...